# Не парсится сайт https://hardprice.ru

Tags: python, requests

```
url = 'https://hardprice.ru/' 
r = requests.get(url)
```

Не получается открыть, пишет ошибку

> ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='hardprice.ru', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url:
> (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.
> VerifiedHTTPSConnection object at 0x7f337ca3ec90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out'))

Comment: Вам же написали: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 110] Connection timed out

Comment: Так, я понял, как это можно обойти?

Comment: Попробуйте селенимум